# Not redirecting to payment page when payment created

Tags: laravel-5.5, mollie

I am trying to integrate laravel-mollie in my website using in the example that they are providing the example. When i'm creating new payment it should redirect me to payment page, But its not showing anything.. here is my code:

```
public function preparePayment($data, $orderId)
{
    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->create([
        'amount' => [
            'currency' => 'EUR',
            'value' => '100.00', // You must send the correct number of decimals, thus we enforce the use of strings
        ],
        "description" => "My first API payment",
        "redirectUrl" => route('mollie.payment.status'),
        'webhookUrl' => route('webhooks.mollie'),
        "metadata" => [
            "order_id" => $orderId,
        ],
    ]);

    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->get($payment->id);

    // redirect customer to Mollie checkout page
    return redirect($payment->getCheckoutUrl(), 303);
}
```

I printed the url. which is showing the link. But not redirecting to the payment page. What did i do wrong! can anyone point me out?

Answer (score 1):

The `$payment` object looks ok, just double check if your param for the `redirectUrl` is correct.

Also if I'm not mistaken the redirect to an external URL in Laravel should be something like:

```
...
return redirect()->away($payment->getCheckoutUrl());
```

Comment: Thanks for you time,, But the problem was, i was using this code in a trait. Thats why it wasn't redirecting..